# Converting ElementCollection to One-Many Relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a situation like this:

```
public class Program{
@Id
private String programid;

@ElementCollection
List<String> productId;

}
```

This creates a table structure like this

### Program

programId -- PK

### Program_ProductId

programId | productId

I want to achieve the same thing, but using Entity Relationship.
One to Many seems the correct way to go, but the table structure cannot change.
Is it the correct option?

Or should I think in terms of Inhertence for mapping such a situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting that into @OneToMany relationship shouldn't be a problem.

```
@Entity
public class Program{
    @Id
    private String programId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="program", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    List<Product> products;
}

@Entity
public class Product {

    @Id
    private String productId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="programId")
    private Program program;
}
```

---

```
Product prod = new Product();
Program prog = new Program();
prog.getProducts().add(prod);
prod.setProgram(prog);
em.persist(prog);
```

Comment: Thanks! This works fine, but the issue is that when i try to cascase using the one to many annotation, it gives me a problem. Does this mean that I need to save every child object. What I was trying to achieve is that all child objects get saved when I save the parent. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes that is possible. You can persist program while its list of products can be automatically persisted using cascade. But since this is bidirectional relationship, you have to update the references on both sides of the relationship before persisting. See updated code.

Comment: cool, it works perfectly with just one glitch now. The IDis an auto-generated one, <see code changes>. The generated ID is not getting set in the Child Object. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I solved the issue. I had insertable = false, updateable = false set somewhere in the code. That has been taken care of now! Works OK! Many thanks!

Comment: good for you. :-) if so,  i kindly request that you accept my post as the answer. Thanks.

Comment: sure. I will do that!